# condor: customizing transfer of input files

Tags: condor

I'd like to process several datafiles on condor in such a way that each node gets its own particular datafile to process. Is there a way to prevent condor from transferring all of the input datafiles to each and every node? It doesn't matter which node gets which file, so long as it's one file per node (and the number of nodes is equal to the number of files). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your submit file send a specific input file based on the process number.  The following lines in your submit file would queue up 100 jobs where each job would use input.0, input.1, ... input.99.

```
Input = in.$(Process)
Queue 100
```